# Difference in Spherical Mercator(google/mapbox/supercluster code) calculation and Postgis 3857

Tags: clustering, web-mercator

As per source code of [supercluster](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster/blob/master/index.js#L324), [google map utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/projection/SphericalMercatorProjection.java#L29) and [mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/076aa8177131a6cd25b7c9ea74af6e95ff2a73fd/src/geo/transform.js#L262) formula to convert (lng, lat) to spherical mercator is as

```
x = lng/360 + 0.5;
siny = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
y = 0.5 * Math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / -(2 * Math.PI) + .5;
```

As per the code this is conversion of (lng, lat) to mercator

Result of above formula for spatial point `(-122.43499755859375, 37.71860885620117)` is `{x=0.15990278455946183, y=0.3867186849275602}`

If I use PostGIS to convert same point to projection 3857 result is

```
POINT(-13629401.5834983 4539750.5916923)
```

Why is there a difference? Leaflet clustering works well with above formula if I have to achieve similar result with PostGIS what kind of projection I must use? Or any more calculations required based on 3857 projection?

Comment: I assumed (and edited) you meant 3857, not 3875 which is a projection for Finland only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code you link to seems to be calculating the values in pixels or 0-1 (in one of the comments) as a preparation  to multiplying it up to pixels on an image. So the values you have calculated are the proportion of the width/height of the world from the south pole/anti meridian.

To get the Web Mercator coordinates in meters you need to do something like, where C is the circumference of the Earth.

```
x = C * 0.15990278455946183 - C/2 
y = -C * 0.3867186849275602 + C/2
```

which for C = 40075000m gives

```
x = -13629395.9088
y = 4539748.70153
```

which is pretty close!

Comment: Web Mercator uses r = 6378137m, so C is 40075016.

Comment: I just used google and took the first answer!

Comment: @iant thanks, its clear now, but there is one more linked question, bringing in the clustering to PostGIS using web mercator. How do I convert zoom levels to web mercator distance so that I can pass details to `ST_ClusterWithIn` or `ST_ClusterDBSCAN`